# How to clean multiple datas by using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder of datas, contain"admin, admin1... admin500", I would like to remove the headers and add column names to the data

```
df = pd.read_csv('admin.tsv', comment='#', header=None, sep='\t',names=['index','count','text','tag'])
```

how do I use a for loop to do every single of the files in that folder, and save them as the same name as before?

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('foldername/*'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, comment='#', header=None, sep='\t',names=['index','count','text','tag'])
    df.to_csv(f'./tmp/{file}')
```

I suppose that the code will be executed in the same folder of data, if note you can relace the `.` with the folder of data in `glob.glob('.')`

Results will be in a tmp folder.

Comment: I changed to ```glob.glob('foldername/*') ``` instead of only ('filename'), is that correct? but after this change it gave me error of AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'.

Comment: My bad ... i edited my respense ^^ you can try it now

Answer (score 0):

Try with `os`:

```
import os

path = "C:/Users/username"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(".tsv")]

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file), 
                     comment='#', 
                     header=None, 
                     sep='\t',
                     names=['index','count','text','tag'])
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(path, file))
```

Note: As mentioned in your question, this will *overwrite* the existing file with the modified `df`.

Comment: somehow after running this code, all the files became the same.

Comment: now its giving me error of ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'admin (3).tsv'``` even tho that is the only file in the folder. I deleted all the other files just to test

Comment: @Eric - I wrongly assumed your files were in your working directory. Re-edited.